# Apply 1D array representing index to element translation over 2D array of index values?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a 2D array

```
arr = np.array([
   [ 1,  2, -1, -1],
   [ 0,  1, -1, -1],
   [ 3,  5, -1, -1],
   [ 7,  8, -1, -1],
   [ 6,  7, -1, -1],
   [ 9, 11, -1, -1]])
```

Its elements are related to the indices of some other array. A `-1` value represent "no index". I also have a translation of the elements in `arr` to some other value (indices of a different array) in the form of

```
trans = np.array([[ 0],
   [-1],
   [ 1],
   [-1],
   [ 2],
   [-1],
   [ 3],
   [-1],
   [ 4],
   [-1],
   [ 5],
   [-1]])
```

Here the `n`th element of `trans` denotes the mapping of the element values in `arr` to the element value of `trans`. For example, a `8` in `arr` should be translated to a value of `4` (`trans[8]` == `4`).

**How can I apply `trans` to translate the values of `arr`?**

Desired output

```
np.array([
    [-1, 1, -1, -1],   
    [0, -1, -1, -1],   
    [-1, -1, -1, -1],  
    [-1, 4, -1, -1],   
    [3, -1, -1, -1],   
    [-1, -1, -1, -1]
])
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: `trans` and `arr` have different dtypes. Which dtype do you want the result to have?

Comment: They should all be `int` valued. Ignore the `float` on `trans`, a result of development and not yet refining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid doing unnecessary lookups into the last element of `trans` for the `-1` entries in `arr` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75225628/11082165)), you can instead create a copy of `arr` and then use similar indexing to only update the non-`-1` entries:

```
result = arr.copy()

has_index = arr != -1
result[has_index] = trans.flat[arr[has_index]].flat

print(repr(result))
```

which outputs

```
array([[-1,  1, -1, -1],
       [ 0, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1,  4, -1, -1],
       [ 3, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

Note that the result will have the dtype of `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

Just flatten `trans`, and index  it with `arr`. Note that this results in the entries that were `-1` in `arr` being translated to the last entry in `trans`. To fix this, you can manually assign `-1` to all entries that were `-1` in `arr`:

```
result = trans.flat[arr]
result[arr == -1] = -1

print(repr(result))
```

outputs

```
array([[-1.,  1., -1., -1.],
       [ 0., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  4., -1., -1.],
       [ 3., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

Note that the result will have the dtype of `trans`.